# Getting user coordinates every X seconds while application is in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, core-location

I want to get user coordinates every X seconds.
I added locations getting in app delegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
...
```

Here I handle new coordinates

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *loc = [locations objectAtIndex:0];

    NSDate* eventDate = loc.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (howRecent < 10)
    {
        CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];

        double lat = location.coordinate.latitude;
        double lng = location.coordinate.longitude;
        NSLog(@"lat:%f lng:%f", lat, lng);
...
```

But I don't know how to continue getting iPhone coordinates when app is in background.
I suppose that I should add some code in:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application...
```

But I don't know what to do to keep location getting a live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your info.plist:

R.Click -> add a row and choose `Required background modes`-> and at item 0 choose `App registers for location updates`

Comment: Just this is required to get coordinates in background? Apple won't reject app with this?

Comment: Sure, its from apple developer

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will open new question for time interval it's better to be new question.